# Generate multiple outputs from the list of inputs

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Please find the below sample script. In this script have given single input $Name to generate the unique loginname.

However,for instance if import the multiple name list from the CSV under $Name, how do  pass the each name from the list to the function to generate the unique loginname and store each ouput unique loginname to the CSV.

### Sample Script:

```
    $Name = "Sample Name"

## Declaring count to 0 .

$i=0

#Define login name
Function New($Count)
{ 
$Splitter = $Name.Split(' ')
$Add1 = $Splitter[0].Substring(0,1)
$Add2 = $Splitter[1].Substring(0,1)

switch($Count)
{
0 {return $LoginName = $Add1+$Add2}
1 {return $LoginName = $Add2+$Add1}
default {return $LoginName = $Add1+$Add2+$Add1}
}
}

#Check AD exist
Function check-ADuser($loginName){

    IF(Get-ADUser -f {samAccountname -eq $LoginName})
        {return $result= $False}
        else {return $result = $True}}
        return $result

#Generate login name
Do{
$loginName = New($i)
$ADresult = check-ADuser -loginName $loginName
$i++

}while($result -ne 'True')
```

Comment: You need a `foreach(){}` loop or a `for(){}` loop to iterate over a collection

Comment: Where do you have `Check-ADUser` defined?

Comment: @trebleCode

I am still not sure about the logic. For instance with foreach() loop can iterate the multiple users and store in the array but as per the above code, how do we pass each stored items in the array to the " Do While" loop to generate the multiple unique login names.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1

I missed the portion of the code, included the Function to define the existence of the user in the AD. Kindly let me know for any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You say you intend to process a CSV file. You should import the CSV into a variable and do a Foreach over that.

If you want to check for an existing account, then maybe you want the `Do` loop to append a number to end of the account name. That could be part of your Check-ADUser function.

For an AD filter, don't use curly brackets in the filter. Best practice is to place it between single quotes.

```
Get-ADUser -f 'samAccountname -eq $LoginName'
```

One more non-code suggestion, from 20 years of NT/AD management:

If your CSV contains the personnel names, don't use people's actual names as login IDs. People change their names for various purposes, and it is *painful* to change account names just because they're getting married or whatever.

If people have an HR/employee number, I highly recommend using that. It's also guaranteed to be unique, and generally less typing than their actual name.